# Get Resultset from MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

I have an application that uses myBatis.
I do not want to convert the resultset from mybatis to a Java object. So essentially I do not want a mapped object. I just want the resultset.
Is it possible to get that from myBatis?
Something like:

```
Resultset resultset = mybatisMapper.getResults();
```

I already have a program which processes this Resultset and I cannot change that program.

Comment: From MyBatis project Readme,md : "MyBatis couples objects with stored procedures or SQL statements using a XML descriptor or annotations", So, probably you don't need MyBatis at all.

Comment: you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43356852/2762716

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a mapped object as result of your query you don't have to use a mapper. Try to take a look to this link, I think it can be useful for you:

[Ibatis/MyBatis select dynamically without need to create any Pojo / Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582034/ibatis-mybatis-select-dynamically-without-need-to-create-any-pojo-mapper)