# MyBatis String as Parameter

Tags: java, database, string, mybatis

I want to use a String parameter for a Select Statement in MyBatis.
My mapper.xml:

```
<select id="selectAll" parameterType="String" resultMap="fastXMLResultMap">
        SELECT CREATIONDATE, DOCUMENTID, TITEL, REGTITEL, INFORCEDATE, DOCTYPE
        FROM #{databBaseTable}
</select>
```

And the calling function:

```
public List<FastXMLObject> selectAll(String databBaseTable) {

    SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

    System.out.println("Table: "+databBaseTable);

    try {
        List<FastXMLObject> list = session.selectList("FastXMLObject.selectAll",databBaseTable);
        return list;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

The string dataBaseTable is the name of the table of my database (who would have thought that) because I want to get data dynamically from verious tables.

But unfortunatelly this does not work: Error: ORA-00903: Ungültiger Tabellenname (invalid table name) but it isnt. When I print out the value of "databBaseTable" it is the exact name of the table. And when I write the name of the table to my mapper.xml without a variable it works.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: you can find the working example [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43357454/2762716

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `${dataBaseTable}` instead of '#'. The difference is that '#' is used for PreparedStatement substitution. '$' is for direct String substitution.

However, if you do this, you can't pass the table name in as a parameter to the `selectList()` call. You need to set the table name as a property. Properties can be set by using the `<properties>` element in the MyBatis config.xml or directly in code by using `Configuration.getVariables()`.

See the 'String Substitution' section in the [MyBatis Docs](http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html).

Comment: Ok I know what you mean but I just cant really figure out what I have to do. I should add ad property to my config.xml like:
`<properties resource="????">
<property name="databBaseTable" value="???"/>
</properties>`

But what should be my ressource and whats the value? I want to set the value dynamically. Sorry but I am totally new to this topic.

Comment: `<properties resource>` loads a properties file. `<properties><property>...` puts the value directly into the MyBatis config xml.
How dynamic do you need the value to be? Just at startup or for each DB call?

Comment: Yes, i am traversing a directory with many subdirectory and each subdirectory represents a table name of the database. So The select From statement has to be totally dynamic. As I wrote below I could figure it out with ${value} but if you know how to put more then one String parameter to the calling function it would be nice, if also not neccesary by now.

Comment: Dude.. Thanks for saving my life.. I was almost about to die just to figure that out why its not working !! :( I didn't notice that I am dealing with table and not its data.

Comment: Usage of ${dataBaseTable} directly can render your code open to injection, if you are not sanitising the input.

Answer (score 7):

Ok I definitely do not know why this works but I just used the following to solve the problem:

```
<select id="selectAll" parameterType="String" resultMap="fastXMLResultMap">
        SELECT CREATIONDATE, DOCUMENTID, TITEL, REGTITEL, INFORCEDATE, DOCTYPE
        FROM ${value}
</select>
```

I did not set any properties or something else, it was just the change from  `FROM #{databBaseTable}` to `FROM ${value}`

I someone could answer why this works would be nice. But for now this really helped me.

Comment: Dude, maybe you should give the credit to AngerClown ?!

Comment: Nabil-Sham - Yes, @AngerClown s answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

With the #{..} syntax MyBatis uses a jdbc PreparedStatement object upon which you cannot specify the table name as a parameter. With #{..} you can only parameterize the parameters of the sql statement.

When you use ${..} syntax MyBatis does plain old string substition so your free to parameterize pretty much any part of the sql you desire.

Note: as a by the way: with #{..} you are pretty safe from sql injection, but with ${..} it does open the door to such attacks

Comment: Could you point out in which lines myBatis PreparedStatement inject the value to those `#{...}`s? I'm learning from myBatis source code...