# Reuse output of one mapper class in another mapper in mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have first mapper as

```
<mapper namespace="org.example.sample1">

     <select id="getHelpPatientInfo" parameterType="hashmap" resultType="patient">
    SELECT ---------

<select>
</mapper>
```

and second mapper as

```
<mapper namespace="org.example.sample2">

     <select id="getpatietDetails" parameterType="hashmap" resultType="patient">
    SELECT ---------

<select>
</mapper>
```

but what i want to do is Reuse the result List i.e. patient from the first mapper as an input for the second mapper so that I will have result of second query based on first query's output.

Please help.!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501069/reusing-mybatis-resultmap-in-multiple-mapper-xml

Comment: @KarthikPrasad : Will you please ellaborate that example for my query..
I am not getting it in my concern.
How do I use result coming from first mapper as an input to second mapper..??