# Mybatis, refer a class from extenal project in Mapper.xml

Tags: java, mybatis

i'm using MybBatis and i'm getting a **ClassNotFound** error which is in an **exnternal project**, and i'm using that class in the **resultMap** in one **Mapper.xml** file.
This is my code:

**-Mapper.xml**: I will only put the resultMapAquí solo colocaré el resultMap, as is the place where i'm getting problems.

```
<resultMap id="BaseResultMapGeneralConfig" type="classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="NUMERIC" property="id" />
    <result column="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
    <result column="value" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="value" />
    <result column="type" jdbcType="NUMERIC" property="type" />
  </resultMap>
```

Note that "type=com.etc...." is the Class in external proyect.
**-The error code i'm getting:**

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
### Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in com/iecisa/tecdoc/sirene/db/map/SireneConfigMapper.xml ### The error occurred while processing mapper_resultMap[BaseResultMapGeneralConfig] ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error inicializando SqlSession. Causa: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ### Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in com/iecisa/tecdoc/sirene/db/map/SireneConfigMapper.xml ### The error occurred while processing mapper_resultMap[BaseResultMapGeneralConfig] ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error creando SqlSession: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error inicializando SqlSession. Causa: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ### Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in com/iecisa/tecdoc/sirene/db/map/SireneConfigMapper.xml ### The error occurred while processing mapper_resultMap[BaseResultMapGeneralConfig] ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
```

I already added the external proyect in my main proyect in the **Projects** tab on **Java Build Path** and i also checked the external project check on **Order and Export** tab.

I tried differents ways, like put the class without the "classpath:", i didn't find the way to solve it.
Any idea? I did some mistake?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501069/reusing-mybatis-resultmap-in-multiple-mapper-xml

Comment: That seems to be another kind of problem, i only want to refer an external class in the type on the resultMap. Thanks btw @MarioPetrovic

Comment: I mean, it seems like `com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig` isn't on the classpath. In any case, unrelated to S2 and XML, so detagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. The problem was on the projects. My main project is a Maven project, but the external is not maven.
So i just get the .jar of the external project, added it via maven on my main project and the dependences on the pom.xml.

And that's all, thanks for your help!