# How to Reuse ResultMap in Mybatis in multiple Mapper.xml in association?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have two tables , Patient and Report and I have created tow mappers pationt-mapper.xml and report-mapper.xml
in pationt-mapper.xml I have write this :

```
<resultMap type="Pationt" id="PationtResult">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="firstname" column="firstname"/>
        <result property="lastname" column="lastname"/>
        <result property="createdAt" column="created_at"/>
</resultMap>
```

in report-mapper.xml I have written this :

```
<resultMap type="Pationt" id="PationtResult">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="firstname" column="firstname"/>
        <result property="lastname" column="lastname"/>
        <result property="createdAt" column="created_at"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="Report" id="ReportResult">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="reportText" column="report_text"/>
        <result property="lastname" column="lastname"/>
        <result property="createdAt" column="created_at" />
        <association property="pationt" resultMap="PationtResult" />
</resultMap>
```

I  repeteed the resultmap over and over in multiple mappers files to use it in association.
How can I reuse resultmap to use it in another mapper file INTO association such as my code :

Answer (score 1):

You can point to the other map using patientMapper.pationtResult in you resultMap Param.

For example:

```
<select id=“getPatientReports”  resultMap=“patientMapper.patientResult”>
…your query here
</select>
```

*here patientMapper is the name space of the mapper you are referring

See below link for more info

[Reusing MyBatis ResultMap in multiple mapper.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501069/reusing-mybatis-resultmap-in-multiple-mapper-xml)